# use Inner Join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I want to join two tables and then I want to join this result with another table
but it doesn't work

```
select * from
        (
            (select SeId,FLName,Company from Sellers) s
                inner join
            (select SeId,BIId from BuyInvoices) b
                on s.SeId=b.SeId                    
            ) Y
            inner join
         (select * from BuyPayments) X
            on Y.BIId=X.BIId
```

thanks

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: you are getting empty set or any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, your syntax isn't going to work.  Although parentheses are allowed in the `FROM` clause, they don't get their own table aliases.

You can simplify the `JOIN`.  This is a simpler way to write the logic:

```
select s.SeId, s.FLName, s.Company, bp.*
from Sellers s inner join
     BuyInvoices b
     on s.SeId = b.SeId inner join
     BuyPayments bp
     on bp.BIId = b.BIId;
```